# how to get a json object via its position in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have an array of json objects and I want to obtain a parameter of the last json object, but when I do it with the code that I will leave below, I get the last character of the string from the end_date parameter of all objects.How can I always get the end_date of the last json object?
I hope you can help me

the array is has the following structure:

```
json = [
    {'id':1,'name':'name1','init_date':'date','end_date':'date'}, 
    {'id':2,'name':'name2','init_date':'date','end_date':'date'},
    {'id':3,'name':'name3','init_date':'date','end_date':'date'},
    {'id':4,'name':'name4','init_date':'date','end_date':'date'}
]
```

My code:

```
tk = token['token_type'] + " " + token['access_token']
url_enterprise = "url"
response_monitor = requests.get(url_enterprise,headers={'Authorization': tk}).json()
for i in reponse_monitor:
   if 'detail' not in response_monitor:
       print(i[end_date][-1])
```

Comment: The question says "I want to obtain a parameter of the last json object", but the code loops over _every_ object in the list.  Those two approaches are not compatible.  So what do you want -- iterate over every object in the list, or get only the last object in the list?

Comment: Also, the code does not appear to refer to your `json` list at all.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use the following to return "end_date" of last json object:

```
json =[{'id':1,'name':'name1','init_date':'date','end_date':'date'}, 
{'id':2,'name':'name2','init_date':'date','end_date':'date'}, 
{'id':3,'name':'name3','init_date':'date','end_date':'date'}, 
{'id':4,'name':'name4','init_date':'date','end_date':'date'}] 

print(json[-1]['end_date'])
```

Comment: I get the error :Keyerror:-1